# Mongo db aggregate convert array to string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

have a collection with data

```
date_new:Array
```

Using mongodb aggregation how to convert into string like this, if there is a empty string convert it into `" "`

```
date_new:Array
    0: " "
```

Comment: can you show me an output from your collection in json?

Comment: @theUnknown : Please check the answer below, I've few question, `date_new : [0:'', 1:'']`, So it has to be an array of objects `date_new : [ {0:' '},{ 1:' '} ]` or with object & it's elements like below result. Also what do you mean by `if there is a empty string convert it into " "` ?? We're converting array how come there will be empty string ? Do you mean an element in `date_new` as empty string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $addFields:
    {
        date_new: {
            $arrayToObject:
            {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$date_new",
                    as: "each",
                    in: [{ $toString: { $indexOfArray: ["$date_new", '$$each'] } }, '$$each']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1e2a74d3c98f2a7100fd44"),
    "date_new" : [ 
        "abc", 
        "def", 
        ""
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1e2f25d3c98f2a7100fd45"),
    "date_new" : []
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1e2a74d3c98f2a7100fd44"),
    "date_new" : {
        "0" : "abc",
        "1" : "def",
        "2" : ""
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1e2f25d3c98f2a7100fd45"),
    "date_new" : {}
}
```